# Alternative proof for the number of edges in a forest

Tags: graph-theory, alternative-proof

I have the following theorem:

Let G be an acyclic graph with n vertices and k connected components. Then G has n-k edges.

I have to prove the above without using induction.

My strategy is to use contrapositive. So if G does not have precisely n-k edges, then either G is not acyclic or it does not have k components.

Does that work at all?
Thanks!

Comment: What is $n$ In your question?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Good question! n is the number of vertices. Thanks!

Comment: I bet you could use spectral graph theory to prove it: a forest is an undirected acyclic graph, and the connected components are the dimension of the nullspace of the Laplacian.

Comment: @user326210 I just got started with my Graph Theory class, so I have no idea of what you are talking about Lol. Is there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: @MorganRodgers My professor already showed us how to do it by induction. He wants us to come up with something different.

Comment: Just to be clear: you require a proof that uses neither induction nor the fact that a tree has $n-1$ edges?  Is the assignment merely to find a proof different than the one you were shown, or have you explicitly been told to avoid induction?  The key insight, in my opinion, is that any graph on $n$ vertices can be built by adding edges to the empty graph on $n$ vertices.  An added edge that does not create a cycle connects two components and therefore reduces the number of components by $1$.  Is the proof you know something along those lines?

Comment: @WillOrrick He told us to avoid induction. We have the following theorem: Let G be an acyclic graph with n vertices and k connected components. Then G has n-k edges. My strategy is to use contrapositive. So if G does not have precisely n-k edges, then either G is not acyclic or it does not have k components. Does that work at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this proof avoids enough inductive reasoning to work. It does identify an invariant of a particular process, but the focus is only ever on a particular graph $G$.

- Let $G$ be an undirected acyclic graph with $k$ connected components and $e$ edges.
- Suppose you remove an edge from $G$ (assuming this is possible.) Because $G$ has no cycles, removing an edge must disconnect two components of the graph. Hence the number of edges goes down by 1, and the number of connected components goes up by one. (Also note that the resulting graph is still acyclic.)
- The quantity $k+e$ is therefore an invariant of this deletion process.
- But if you delete *all* of the edges in the graph $G$, you end up with the empty graph: a graph with $n$ connected components and no edges. For the empty graph, $k^\prime+e^\prime = n + 0 = n$. Hence by invariance, $k+e = n$ for the original graph $G$, as well.
- Hence $e = n-k$, as required.

Comment: identifying this invariant was definitely clever! I was getting at something similar by noticing that removing an edge means increasing the number of components. But you definitely helped me organize my thoughts. Thanks!

Comment: @PabloMello No worries. I think the proof still has some "inductive character", because it could have been written "the empty graph has this property, and so (because of invariance) does any acyclic extension of a graph with this property". But the argument here is not quite by mathematical induction, so I hope that'll suffice.